# Comparing to systimestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get all records updated within the last hour using the below query.

```
select * from myTable where update_time > systimestamp - interval '1' hour;
```

I was pretty sure systimestamp took the timezone of the database and not the timezone of my machine (I am in CDT (-5), the DB is in UTC). When I ran the above query, it gives me results within the last 6 hours. Even more interestingly, I run this query with the following results:

```
select systimestamp, update_time from myTable where update_time > systimestamp - interval '1' hour order by update_time asc;

SYSTIMESTAMP                           UPDATE_TIME                   
-------------------------------------- -------------------------------
20-AUG-14 05.27.34.534438000 PM +00:00 20-AUG-14 11.27.53.882180000 AM 
20-AUG-14 05.27.34.534438000 PM +00:00 20-AUG-14 11.33.47.677019000 AM 
20-AUG-14 05.27.34.534438000 PM +00:00 20-AUG-14 11.40.24.751760000 AM 
20-AUG-14 05.27.34.534438000 PM +00:00 20-AUG-14 11.43.03.276697000 AM 
20-AUG-14 05.27.34.534438000 PM +00:00 20-AUG-14 11.44.26.439896000 AM 
20-AUG-14 05.27.34.534438000 PM +00:00 20-AUG-14 11.53.17.772865000 AM 
20-AUG-14 05.27.34.534438000 PM +00:00 20-AUG-14 11.53.51.116485000 AM 
...
```

Why am I seeing these results?

Update: These Queries work:

```
select * from myTable where FROM_TZ(update_time, 'UTC') > systimestamp - interval '1' hour;
select * from myTable where update_time > CAST(systimestamp AS TIMESTAMP) - interval '1' hour;
```

My question, more specifically, is how do I get the system to interpret a timestamp value as UTC (or even better, to interpret it in the DB timezone) by default rather than interpreting a timestamp in local time of my machine?

Comment: What datatype is `update_time`? Looks like a plain `timestamp` from the format, whereas `systimestamp` is `timestamp with time zone`. One or the other is being converted to your local time zone (like `current_timestamp` would show)?

Comment: Update_time is of timestamp(6)